# What kind of cockroach is this?

Tags: bugs, germany, bug-identification

What species is the following cockroach?  Is it dangerous, that means is it likely to transport diseases? I live in South Germany.

> [image]
>  [image]

Comment: You may want to split up the question. One for the first insect and one for the second. As far as I can tell you would've already an answer for the first one :) What do you think?

Comment: @OddDeer you are right, I did split it in two.

Answer (score 6):

The first one could be a German cockroach (Blattella germanica). The seconds one though… not sure if it is a cockroach?

Perhaps you could catch sharper photos with a bit more lighting?

Comment: Thx. I shot two more pics and uploaded them but my camera is bad, especially shooting through glass. The german wiki says, that the first one is maybe *Ectobius vittiventris* (no black stripes at the head) which is often mistaken to be *Blattella germanica*. Still I am not sure if this is right.

Comment: the second one is not a cockroach. it looks a lot like this one http://www.cerambyx.uochb.cz/pedostrangalia_revestita.php a Pedostrangalia revestita

Comment: @Peter1807 thx for your comment. I splitted the question, you can post an answer here: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13708/is-this-a-cockroach-if-so-which-one