# Is this a cockroach? If so, which one?

Tags: bugs, germany, bug-identification

What species is the following? I assume it is a cockroach, but I am not sure. What is it exactly? I live in South Germany.

> [image]
>  [image]

Comment: It isn't obnoxious, just a mild nuisance. But as many people panic at the sight of a large insect or arachnid, I approve of the use of spoiler tags here so it can remain SFW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a Pedostrangalia revestita (i totally ripped this from the site below. I have no idea if this is correct, I am still looking for the English and German terms (in German it is a kind of Bockkäfer))

http://cerambyx.uochb.cz/pedostrangalia_revestita.php

I am by no means an expert, but those look alike. The wing-covers have similar shapes, red legs, big eyes, the butt-brush.

Some coleopterist might come to improve on this answer with proper terminology, please don't forget to laugh about the word butt-brush.

Edit: on a German page i have found another similar one: Rhamnusium bicolor, the "Beulenkopfbock" (german) (but, similar to the other source, I found conflicting images on different sites)

http://www.naturspaziergang.de/Kaefer/Cerambycidae/Rhamnusium_bicolor.htm